# How to find out the pinned vCPUs?

Tags: virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I am working on a setup where I am running a Ubuntu VM on a Fedora 18 host using QEMU/KVM and libvirt. Now I have pinned 2 vCPUs to my VM. I can see the pinned vCPUs using virsh. But, is there any other way to find that out? Ideally, I want to write a function which will return the number/id of pinned vCPUs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use element  in domain XML to determine which pinned CPUs for which vcpu. see section [CPU Tuning](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsCPUTuning). By default, the vcpu is pinned to all physical CPUs.

For example:

```
<cputune>
<vcpupin vcpu="0" cpuset="1-4,^2"/>
<vcpupin vcpu="1" cpuset="0,1"/>
</cputune>
```

Comment: Actually what I want to know is that if there is any way I can write an API, that can return me the number of overall pinned CPUs on the system. Suppose I am running 2 VMs, now there is separate XML file for each VM. I want to know how many CPUs have been pinned on that host.

Comment: According to libvirt, you can use method [virDomainGetVcpuPinInfo](http://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt.html#virDomainGetVcpuPinInfo) and there're a number of language bindings that you can choose. Generally you can use command **taskset** to query your VM process on hypervisor to see which pinned CPU it uses like this: `taskset -c -p 1366` (assume your qemu process PID is 1366)

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. That works. Dont mind me asking, but I have one more issue. My VM's XML file has the vCPU attribute defined as:
<vcpu placement='static' cpuset='1,2,3'>3</vcpu>
Now, when I tried taskset, its showing the affinity as 0-3.